# How could I call function in a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

How could I call the function 'gotopage' below in javascript?

I used 'gotopage(5);',but the browser points out the function is not defined.So what is the correct answer to call the function in others' jQuery plugin?

```
;(function ($) {

$.fn.booklet = function (options, param1, param2) {

  //..............
};

function Booklet(inTarget, inOptions) {

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    return {
        init: init,
        enable: enable,
        disable: disable,
        destroy: destroy,
        next: next,
        prev: prev,
        gotopage: function (index) {
            //.............
            goToPage(index);
        },
        add: addPage,
        remove: removePage,
        option: function (name, value) {
           //.............
        }
    }
}

// define default options
$.fn.booklet.defaults = {
     //...........
}

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: That's... a lot of code. Please reduce to the necessary part. Calling a function in general is easy, just add `()` after its name, e.g. `foo()`.

Comment: Sorry, but I tried, the browser points out the function is not defined.The function is here.

Comment: Can you exactly tell where do you want to call "gotopage" function.

Comment: In the javascript.Just like when the page is loaded,the function should be called.

Answer (score 1):

"goToPage" is a function "inside" another function "Booklet" and this again is inside another anonymous function (as far as I can see).

You can't call this function directly from outside this function. You need to call if from the same scope.

And here is the solution quickly found by reading the Plugin Documentation:

```
$('#custom-goto').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mybook').booklet("gotopage", "end");
    });
```

Comment: Is there any way to call it from outside this function not directly?

Comment: Which jQuery Plugin is it? Normally, they have a documentation about how to call certain functions directly.

Comment: I want to acheive that to control the page with inputting the page number.But the document only contains pageSelector.

Comment: So I want to call the function 'goToPage' it already contains to achieve it.

Comment: You are looking for a certain "event". See here: http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/demos/methods Everything is explained in simple examples.

Answer (score 0):

goToPage(index) is a private function it couldn't be called outside the plugin.Try creating function globally using $.fn.

> $.fn.goToPage=function(index){
>   }

Comment: But the function 'goToPage' is inside the functin 'Booklet', when I tried it errors.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps ..i haven't tried testing it

```
 `(function ($) {

$.fn.booklet = function (options, param1, param2) {

    //..............
};

function Booklet(inTarget, inOptions) {

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    return {
        init: init,
        enable: enable,
        disable: disable,
        destroy: destroy,
        next: next,
        prev: prev,
        gotopage: function (index) {
            //.............
            $.fn.goToPage(index);
        },
        add: addPage,
        remove: removePage,
        option: function (name, value) {
            //.............
        }
    }
}

// define default options
$.fn.booklet.defaults = {
    //...........
}
$.fn.goToPage=function(index){
 //function is now public
};
```

})(jQuery);

`